# [YouTube IFrame][Android] How to remove YouTube logo from mobile browser

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

We put a YouTube video on our web page using the YouTube iframe API. The iframe src looks like below.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/AUBTAdI7zuY?version=3&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&theme=dark&playsinline=1&origin=testing&vq=medium&enablejsapi&autoplay=0

When viewing the page through laptop browser, like Chrome and Safari,
YouTube logo is hidden with the param `modestbranding=0`.

But when viewing the same page on Android Chrome, the logo is visible and covers on the video.

Is there any iframe params or any way to remove YouTube logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the solution on our case here.
The root cause is the width and height we provided are too small.

As stated in [YouTube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), the size should be at least 200px by 200px.

> Embedded players must have a viewport that is at least 200px by 200px. If the player displays controls, it must be large enough to fully display the controls without shrinking the viewport below the minimum size. We recommend 16:9 players be at least 480 pixels wide and 270 pixels tall.

We ended up with giving the embed iframe fixed size and applying CSS transform to the whole page.

Then this problem is patched.

Answer (score 0):

I have used YouTube's API in my mobile app before and ran into a similar problem. 
What I found is that YouTube always makes sure there is a way to link back to their site.

Even in a *desktop/laptop browser* when you move the mouse the YouTube link is on the far right side of the video's progress bar.

For a *mobile device* there is no mouse so instead of placing it on the progress bar they put a static link in the corner of the video.

There may be a way to cover it up by placing something on top of it using HTML and JavaScript. I am pretty sure this will breach the licence agreement so I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thank you! Then instead of removing the logo, is there any possible way to make it smaller? We don't want to breach the agreement but the logo is large and covers the whole embed video and the play button.

Comment: I am not sure why that is happening for you. When I view the URL you gave on my mobile phone using chrome it showed up as a small icon in the lower right hand side of my screen. It is very small and not too large at all. What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Android Chrome. I found out the cause. As stated in [YouTube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), the recommended player size is 200px by 200px but I assign the values smaller. Thank you for helping me on this.